# MsChart part update instead of complete refresh in c#

Tags: c#, mschart

I am working on a project where I am plotting the points against time using MsChart.
My problem is as the time moves ahead MsChart looses the speed.
I am updating 127 points per second. (128Hz) this is my worst case.
Time scale is fixed as well as interval.
What I observed is MsCHart repaint complete graph on each point update (which is a overhead) 
Is there any option of changing this to part update or update only new point ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way I know to refresh only a part of a ChartArea. However, I use some tips to optimize charting:

- First, I use the most optimized ChartType for display to my Series

Enum:

```
SeriesChartType.FastLine
SeriesChartType.FastPoint
```

- Also, I apply the `.SuspendUpdates()` and `.ResumeUpdates()` methods to the Series collection before I add new points:

Example:

```
myChart.Series.SuspendUpdates();

// Adding points
...

myChart.Series.ResumeUpdates();
```

- Also, adusting the min max range of the X axis to display only a subset of all the points might help.

If it is not good enough, then your requirements are probably exceeding MsChart capabilities.

In this case I suggest to switch to the [ZedGraph](http://sourceforge.net/projects/zedgraph/) library. It is old, but is still the best in term of footprint and performances and it never disappointed me.

---

**EDIT**

Because I am surprised ZedGraph gave you bad results, I put here a quick and dirty **zedgraph sample** that try its best to match your specifications:

- It handles 3600s of 128hz dots in a RollingPointPairList (a special FIFO point list)
- It adds 128dots to the graph each seconds

Just copy/paste it in a Form_Load event to give it a try. It uses random values and displays the whole chart when it starts, so it may look very ugly at first sight.

However, you can zoom using mouse selection and wheel, or pan using CTRL+Click moving the mouse, then see if the performances reach your expectations.

```
var fq = 128; // Freq in hz
var maxDuration = 3600; // max duration in s

var zg1 = new ZedGraphControl();
zg1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
this.Controls.Add(zg1);

var myPane = zg1.GraphPane;
myPane.XAxis.Type = AxisType.Date;
myPane.XAxis.Scale.Format = "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.mmm";

var list = new RollingPointPairList(maxDuration * fq);

var ran = new Random();
var getRandomValue = new Func<double, double, double>((min, max) => ran.NextDouble() * (max - min) + min);

var ts = DateTime.Now;

for (var i = 0; i < list.Capacity; i++)
{
    list.Add(new XDate(ts), getRandomValue(50d, -50d));
    ts = ts.AddMilliseconds(1000d / fq);
}

var myCurve = new LineItem("dots", list, Color.Red, SymbolType.None, 1);
myCurve.Line.IsOptimizedDraw = true;
myPane.CurveList.Add(myCurve);

zg1.AxisChange();
zg1.Invalidate();

var z = new Timer();
z.Interval = 1000;
z.Tick += (s, ev) =>
    {
        var points = myCurve.Points as RollingPointPairList;
        for (var i = 0; i < fq; i++)
        {
            points.Add(new XDate(ts), getRandomValue(50d, -50d));
            ts = ts.AddMilliseconds(1000d / fq);
        }

        zg1.Invalidate();
    };

z.Start();
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. I am already using the fastline and suspendUpdate. But still its not good enough. Looking at the ZedGraph.

Comment: Hi, I tried ZedGraph Performing bad than MsCHart Can you suggest something else.

Comment: This is very surprising. Are you sure the problem is not the amount of dot displayed (reduce the min max interval of on the x-axis too see), or it can be the data retrieval that occurs before ?

Comment: My problem is i can not have fixed min max, its all controllable by user at run time. And the allowed range for user is very high. ( from 1 sec to 3600 sec). THis software is basically working with device in real time at frequency of 128 Hz ( which is very high according to me for operating systems like Windows as its not real time) Though i managed the display now MsChart by the same technique you suggested with an algorithm of self adopting suspendUpdate interval.

Comment: I shared a ZedGraph sample trying my best to match your requirements. It may look ugly at first sight because I have no idea of the min max y values of your data and I use random value. But playing with zooming panning zedgraph capabilities should give you an idea about how it could perform handling 460800 dots :)

Comment: oops, another edit done: I forgot to add myCurve.Line.IsOptimizedDraw = true; in the code.